# Como cambiar status de una orden SortableJS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

quisiera saber quien ha trabajado con SortableJS para los drag and drop, estoy haciendo un trabajo para mi oficina y quisiera saber como hago el cambio de status cuando hago el cambio de casilla o campo. mi codigo es el siguiente.AYUDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

var revision = document.getElementById('revision'),
    impresion = document.getElementById('impresion'),
    terminado = document.getElementById('terminado'),
    finalizado = document.getElementById('finalizado');



var revision_d = Sortable.create(revision, {
    group: 'shared', 
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function () {
        
    },
});

var impresion_d = Sortable.create(impresion, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function () {
        
    },
});

var terminado_d = Sortable.create(terminado, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function (orden) {

    },
});

var finalizado_d = Sortable.create(finalizado, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
    chosenClass: "select",
    dragClass: "ghost",
    ghostClass: "dmove",
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onEnd: function (orden) {
        
    },
});
```

aca dejo el codigo solo que no sabia que eran tan sencibles con respecto a los codigos :/

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el código debe incluirse como texto y no en una imagen.

Comment: a qué te refieres con status ?

Comment: Es que voy a manejar un status por cada tabla, ya que es para una imprentan entonces son 4 estados:

1: Revision
2: Impresion
3: Terminados
4: Finalizado

y pues quiero manejar todo con un drag and drop con el SortableJS para agilizar el proceso a los trabajadores de las 3 areas principales, y ps al cambiar de revision a impresion se cambie el status en la base de datos